# API Key for access to google maps

Tags: android

For google maps I need MD5 fingerprint to get my API Key for access the problem is that when I am writing this code in cmd.

```
keytool -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

it says that I need to enter a password but so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The password is the one you used to create the keystore.

Answer (score 0):

You might have given a password while creating the key and keystore.

Provide it with that password!

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a lot of people with this same issue...which I continue to have. This question mentions an MD5 signature, but the documentation at Google is asking for an SHA-1 key. Anyway, by default, the password in an ADT installation of Eclipse is : android